# ATtiny85 eeprom write in the arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, eeprom, attiny

I have a problem: I can read the EEPROM from my ATtiny, but I can't write something in it.

Here is my code:

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

int addr = 0;
int val = 2;
    
void setup()
{
}
    
void loop()
{
  EEPROM.write(addr, val);
      
  addr = addr + 1;
  if (addr == 512)
    addr = 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Now my write code is:

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

int addr = 0;
int val = 2;

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
  EEPROM.write(addr, byte(val));
  
  addr = addr + 1;
  if (addr == 512)
    while(1);
}
```

And my read code:

```
int address = 0;
byte value;

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

void setup()
{
  SSerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  value = EEPROM.read(address);
  
  SSerial.print(address);
  SSerial.print("\t");
  SSerial.print(value, DEC);
  SSerial.println();
  
  address = address + 1;
  
  if (address == 512){
    address = 0;
    delay(100000000);
  }
}
```

I always get only teh value 255. On every adress.
Now I convert my int to byte. My int won't get over 255 in my case.

And by the way: can I create an int as byte? So I can use it like a normal int, but can write it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing a single byte, whereas an `int` is two bytes. You can use `EEPROM.get()` & `EEPROM.put()` for larger types (read/write only handle a single byte).

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
int addr = 0;
int val = 2;

void setup(){}

void loop(){

  //Write value
  EEPROM.put(addr, val);

  //Read value
  EEPROM.get(addr, val);

  addr += sizeof(int);  //Increment cursor by two otherwise writes will overlap.

  if(addr == EEPROM.length())
    addr = 0;
}
```

as Vladimir Tsykunov mentioned, this test code can be bad for your EEPROM as it will loop many times while running. It may be better to stop the loop after one iteration:

```
  if(addr == EEPROM.length())
    while(1); //Infinite loop
```

Comment: I got it to work. But why I need my value to read? With read() I got only 255.

Comment: @SPJS01Pro You must be using an old version of the IDE, my EEPROM lib replaced the original in version 1.6.2 and above. This includes get,put, and length. As for getting 255 for each read, this value is the default/cleared value for an EEPROM cell, so it doesn't look like any thing has been written. In your 'write sketch' add in `SSerial.println( EEPROM.read(addr), DEC );` to verify you have written something.

Comment: I gonna try it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now it works! But the the Attiny losts the data after I turned off the power.

Answer (score 0):

Try not write eeprom in a loop, i suppose, eeprom have limited number of write/read cycles. You should show values that you read and write in terminal.

Comment: I tried in the setup() section. :/ Doesn't work too.

Comment: From you code we cant know if memory was written or not.